# How to hide images until AFTER jquery flexslider finishes loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider, woothemes

I tried to integrate wootheme's Flexslider on my site and it looks/works great except for when it is loading.

When you refresh the page with the slider, before flexslider loads (about 1 second) the first slide appears very big and flashes to black then dissapears and then the carousel appears.

I think the image is loading faster than the jquery? How can I hide the image unti jquery loads (like on the demo website, even if i refresh 3 billion times, the problem is never repeated on their website, it all loads gracefully! -  http://flexslider.woothemes.com/carousel-min-max.html )

I loaded the flexlisder.js right after jquery and copied the same html code from the demo (to match the .css file that is also loaded. And here is the init code I am using - from the demo site also:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    minItems: 2,
    maxItems: 4
  });
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to deal with the **callback functions** for the plugin you are using 
hide all the images from CSS by using a class let's say `flexImages`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    minItems: 2,
    maxItems: 4, 
    start: function(){
         $('.flexImages').show(); 
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that did the trick! Woothemes didn't mention doing that, yet their demos work perfect regardless!

Comment: I am glad it helped, but my advice to you is when you face such problems with plugins or such stuff read about their callbacks it really will help :)

Answer (score 6):

Set the default style for "display" to "none".  using show() will change this style value.

Comment: I want to add: It is important to do this on <li> elements.

Answer (score 1):

Also Found that the slides flash before loading and display stacked down the page with list item bullets.

Only for a second. Then it worked fine. I didn't realize I hadn't included the flexslider.css file because I had already turned of any navigation that would have shown broken nav img links.

Remember to Include the CSS!

Answer (score 1):

… i had the same problem, tried the js solution above - it worked well but then i realized when js is disabled for some reason - that nothing will be shown up, so i decided to look for a non js solution:

i just put some thing like that for the specific slider:

```
.MySlider {
  .flexslider .slides img { 
  max-height: 400px; 
  width: 940px;
 }
}
```

worked well, even responsive. Hope that may help!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue when I forgot to include the flexslider.css

Answer (score 0):

I just set in the CSS of the div that contains the slider: overflow:hidden ; height: the height of the images you use, then it works perfect!

update: this  is not a responsive solution as the slider changes the size... what can I do??